# Express 4 empty JSON query

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using ReactJS as frontend and Nodejs (Express) as the API. I can't seem to be able to grab the JSON values of the request sent by the react service in Nodejs. I am able to call the POST route and even recieve a reply bu tthe req.body seems to be empty. Here's the Fetch function I use in React:

```
static Post(url, bodyArgs){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fetch(apiUrl+url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(bodyArgs),
      //{eventID: 1}
  })
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((resJson) => {
    //console.log(resJson);
    return resJson;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    //console.error(err);
    return err;
  });
});
```

}

And this is the code I use on my route (accounts.js):

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
  res.json({requestBody: req.body}) 
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))

  console.log("got it")

  console.log(username+" <> "+password);
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

I've already added the JSON middleware on my main app.js file:

```
var accountsRouter = require('./routes/accounts');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var eventsRouter = require('./routes/events');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/accounts', accountsRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/events', eventsRouter);
```

Why is it not working? Is it because I have to include the Json middleware on my router file as well?

EDIT: I'm using Express@4.16.3

Comment: "the req.body seems to be empty" Can you be more specific?

Comment: Well, when I attempt to read the values I've sent, there are no values inside. It's just an empty array, which means JSON isn't actually being parsed.

Comment: So `JSON.stringify(req.body)` returns a string containing `[]`?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))` returns `{}`

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed bodyParser.
Add `app.use(express.bodyParser());` in your app.js
For newer versions of express > 4 try

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: I'm using Express 4.16.3 which makes bodyParser deprecated. You can see on the last snippet that I included the new method **express.json()**

Comment: earlier it was part of express body-parser. now you have to install and import it separately. i.e. npm install body-parser --save

Comment: express.json() and bodyParser are the same modules pretty much, at least that's what the docs say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178543/discussion-between-mehta-rohan-and-iuri-dias).

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, it's due to CORS. I set up my `fetch()` CORS parameter to **no-cors** which means the browser can no longer do advanced requests such as JSON or any other custom headers. To fix this issue, you simply need to do the following:

Remove this parameter from your fetch function:

```
mode: "no-cors"
```

And then add, on your Express app, the following code:

```
// CORS enable
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Now that your API server accepts CORS, everything should work fine.